# XSL - Display XML tags based on parameter from PHP

Tags: xslt, parameters

Ive got a problem displaying my desired XML tags based on an parameter. I'm fairly new to this.

XML Example:

```
<car name="Toyota">
   <model nr="123" yeardate="2010">
      <owner ssn="123456789" name="Tom"/>
      <owned years="0" months="6"/>
   </model>
</car>
<car name="Volvo">
   <model nr="222" yeardate="2009">
      <owner ssn="345364774" name="John"/>
      <owned years="0" months="8"/>
   </model>
</car>
<car name="Fiat">
   <model nr="333" yeardate="2010">
      <owned years="0" months="0"/>
   </model>
</car>
```

The problem is that I want to be able to choose the car that is displayed BASED on an HTML form I made in my PHP document. So, I made a form in PHP, sent the value of POST back to my XSL document and now I want to display the car based on this parameter value. Also, notice that the car Fiat does not have an owner. I am able to get the value of POST in my XSL document, but I'm not sure how I go about using this parameter.

What I imagine this turning in to: 
Lets say that Toyota is choosen in the form,

```
car name=Toyota

model nr=123 yeardate=2010

owner ssn=123456789 name=tom

owned years=0 months=6
```

I want to include the tag name as well as all the attributes.

Comment: your code is missing, also its not clear what your problem is and which of the existing answers didn't help you. List them and tell what did not work for you.

Comment: [del-ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564345/xsl-parse-xml-with-paramter-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, maybe you don't need XSL. Have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php).

```
<?php
$xmlString = '<root>
    <car name="Toyota">
       <model nr="123" yeardate="2010">
          <owner ssn="123456789" name="Tom"/>
          <owned years="0" months="6"/>
       </model>
    </car>

    <car name="Fiat">
       <model nr="333" yeardate="2010">
          <owned years="0" months="0"/>
       </model>
    </car>
</root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
    if ( (string) $second_gen['name'] == "Toyota") {
        echo $second_gen->asXML();
    }
}
?>
```